# Should this be a one-way repeated measures anova?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, spss

I'm a new phd researcher and I just completed my first set of experiments. Participants played the same game using three different control mechanisms. In the game they had to complete a series of tasks, with the time taken to complete each task recorded. Participants used the three different control mechanisms in a random order.

I have the data stored in two different styles. The first one being each version being on a separate row for each participant. The second being all version times are on the same row for each participant with the ".Number" representing which technique it is (this was done by SPSS when I converted it to 'wide'). In the wide, the order in which techniques were done varies but to keep things consistent the technique order in the data is the same for everyone. So if the techniques were mouse (1), games controller (2) and wii remote (3). If they were ordered as seen in the brackets and a participants did them in 2,3,1 and another did it in 2,1,3. The ".1" times would all refer to the mouse technique.

[image]

[image]

I have done a one-way repeated measures anova comparing using the total game times and the techniques. Although I'm not sure this is correct now. I was trying to compare the total game times to look for anything significant. I followed a guide on Laerd, but now I'm doubting I've done it right. I added time which has three levels and then added the completion times for each of the three techniques (the second image).

[image]

[image]

I'm also trying to analyse the effect the different techniques had on task completion times, but I have no idea what I'm doing.

I've spent several hours searching online, watching youtube videos and reading tutorials and I felt confident I had done my first test right until I started trying to do this second one. Now I'm not sure.

Many thanks

UPDATE:
Ok, so the three techniques are vr motion controllers, vr gloves and an optical based tracker. I'm using the motion controllers as the baseline and I'm comparing the performance of the other two against it. I'm looking for statistical differences. My hypothesis that my current one-way repeated measures anova (assuming I've done it correctly) proves/shows is that the glove offers a middle ground solution with there being significant differences between optical tracker and motion controller but none between gloves and other two. I feel like ANOVA is the way to go but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Your question doesn't come across as stupid, but it is not very concise. Perhaps you should start with a research question/hypothesis before explaining what the data look like. Then explain how your data is supposed to answer this research question. From there it will be easier to recommend a statistical test or model.

Comment: Ok, so the three techniques are vr motion controllers, vr gloves and an optical based tracker. I'm using the motion controllers as the baseline and i'm comparing the performance of the other two against it. I'm looking for statistical differences. My hypothesis that my current one-way repeated measures anova (assuming i've done it correctly) proves/shows is that the glove offers a middle ground solution with there being significant differences between optical tracker and motion controller but none between gloves and other two. I feel like ANOVA is the way to go but i'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: I think you're thinking in the right direction. However, be careful how you interpret a non-significant result: it is *not* proof of no difference. If you want to demonstrate that one group is between the other two, perhaps you'd be best off simply plotting the three categories next to each other. On a different note, since these data are waiting times, they may not be approximately normally distributed (they tend to be right skewed). In that case, you could for example use a generalized linear mixed model with an exponential error structure, instead of an RM-ANOVA.